# Connect with FTP to Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, ftp

I'm new to Docker and I'm using this Microsoft SQL Server Docker Image

```
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I've run the container on my linux server with this command which is from the microsoft doc:

```
    sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
    -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \ 
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I can connect with ssh when I'm on my server with this command:

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how I can connect to this container with FTP.

I thought installing ftp on the image and then run with something like:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
    -p 1433:1433 -p 21:21 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \ 
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

But I can't run it again without removing the image.
I Would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: A Docker container runs only one program.  In your case, it's a SQL Server container; it does not contain an ssh daemon, an FTP server, or anything else a full virtual machine would include.  You should interact with it the same way you'd interact with a SQL Server _process_ outside a container: use an appropriate client library for your application, but there's no reason to "get a shell inside the database server" or "FTP files into the database server".

Comment: Actually I need a ftp access or any other way to move an existing database into it..

Answer (score 0):

You are not editing the image but the container that you create with that command.

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
    -p 1433:1433 -p 21:21 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \ 
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Just run that command to create your container and use that container via

```
docker start sql1
```

and

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
```

and if you want to have an image of your container after you edited your Container, use the

```
docker commit sql1
```

or so. (You might read the documentation on docker commit for correct syntax.)

UPDATE:

As of the comments below, I'd like to recommend you to get yourself confident with the docker file usage instead of docker commit.

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice and I would not recommend it.  Of particular note, most of the standard database containers are configured so that, even if you do commit an image, it doesn't contain the database data.  More critically, if you've modified and committed an image and then the original image has a security update, you'll need to remember exactly what you did to rebuild your derived image.

Comment: Yes.  To update SQL Server in a container "you must create a new container with the latest SQL Server container image and migrate your data to that new container." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash#upgrade

Comment: Do you know a way to move a existing database.db file into the container ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a way to get an FTP Access but the main purpose was to be able to move a file from the host into the container.

The way to do that is as simple as a ssh cp

```
sudo docker cp foo.txt containerID:/foo.txt
```

Thanks for the answers